# Contact Us works on local machine, but not on bluehost.com

Tags: 7, emails

How can I track down why an email is not generated from my new web site when I click Contact on the Contact page?

I turned on maillog and devel. What I get is 
    maillog =>
        ... (Array, 6 elements)
 ... (Array, 6 elements)

```
Subject (String, 23 characters ) [Website feedback] test
From (String, 22 characters ) sam.stamport@gmail.com
To (String, 22 characters ) sam.stamport@gmail.com
Reply-To (NULL)
Header (Array, 7 elements)
Body (String, 128 characters ) admin (http://columbiablooms.org/users/admin) s... 
    Krumo version 0.2.1a | http://krumo.sourceforge.net
    [Click to expand. Double-click to show path.] Called from
    /home5/columck5/public_html/sites/all/modules/maillog/includes/maillog.mail.inc
    , line
    90

Your message has been sent.
```

Error message:

> Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

Comment: Check this page and the comments for clues : https://www.drupal.org/node/1491914 I'd say it's a connection parameters problem.

Comment: Probably a smtp issue ? have you try https://drupal.org/project/smtp ?

Comment: If you haven't enabled SMTP (which is a rad module), you should follow up with Bluehost and raise a ticket with them. If it's a share platform then email should be working with the base `mail()` function in PHP.

Comment: I just received the specifications for SMTP from bluehost, but am dog tired after watering plants (that my new web site facilitates) out in the heat. I'll work on this tomorrow and post back here the results. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Installing the SMTP module and configuring it correctly was the solution to the problem. Since I am a newbie to Drupal it seems magical that it solved the problem. I don't fully understand the logic flow of SMTP and SimpleNewsletter.

It took three different chats with bluehost before I got SMTP configured correctly.

Following are the SMTP parameters that finally worked. The email address in Home » Administration » Configuration » System - Site Information also was incorrect. I set it to admin@columbiablooms.org and everything finally worked. The admin@columbiablooms.org email address had to first be created via cpanel at bluehost. The password in the screenshots below is the one that I used when I created the email address at bluehost.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope all this helps another newbie ...